# Local variables implementation

Tags: environment-variables, fish

I've been using the fish shell for a bit now, and I've recently had a conversation with a coworker over local variables. Apparently, Bash doesn't support local variables, and only uses environment variables to communicate dynamic data between processes. Are local variables also just environment variables, but with something extra? I'm curious as to how fish has created this behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Bash doesn't support local variables

That's not true. Bash (and other shells including dash - it's one of the few POSIX extensions it has) have the `local` keyword to create local variables. They just default to global, while fish defaults to local.

Also when you say "environment variables" what you mean are "exported" variables, which require an explicit "export" step in posixy shells, and the "-x" or "--export" flag to `set` in fish.

I e. there are two different things at play here - whether this variable is available just in this function/block/whatever, and not the outside, and whether it is passed on to *children*, including external processes.

> Are local variables also just environment variables, but with something extra?

Non-exported variables are something *less*. They aren't given to the OS's `setenv` function, so it doesn't copy them to child processes.

Local variables are removed when the block ends. In practice this can be done nicely by putting them on a stack and "popping" the top.

Note that, in fish at least, these concepts are entirely orthogonal:

You can have local-exported variables (with `set -lx`), and they'll be passed to external commands and copied to functions (so they get their own local version of it), but removed when the function ends.  These are useful to change something temporary - e.g. to set $PATH just for a function, or to override $EDITOR when calling something.

And you can have global-unexported variables, which can be accessed by functions but not external commands. These are useful for shell settings like $fish_function_path, which isn't useful to external tools, or $COLUMN, which might even break external tools if exported (because they start to read it instead of checking the terminal size themselves).

Comment: Sorry for the misconception, you seem to be correct about bash. So, local variables aren't passed to child processes because they don't get passed to `setenv`; what's the reason they stay in their function/block/whatever? Is that indirectly the same thing?

Comment: The reason they do is because they're implemented that way - e.g. a variable "stack" with a layer popped off once the block ends. How exactly that works depends on the shells internals, but it'll roughly be the parser (because shell execution is typically quite intertwined with parsing) popping off a node once a block ends.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some misconceptions here:

- bash can have variables that are local to a function: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-local
- Not every shell (bash/fish/etc) variable is in the environment. This is why the `export` (bash) and `set -x` (fish) commands exist.
- For two separate processes to share the same variable value, you must pass them via the environment. The environment is the way to expose shell variables to other processes.